# How to convert the Node.js date format to oracle datetime format

Tags: node.js, oracle

I need to convert the  Node.js datetime '2016-07-13T07:38:15.500Z' to oracle format, where as the .500z represents the timezone.

Im using oracle 11g

Comment: How does "`.500z`" represent a timezone? Are you sure that doesn't mean `0.5` seconds?

Answer (score 1):

The `.500z` doesn't represent the time zone. The `.500` is fractional seconds. The `z` is short for Zulu, which means the time zone has been normalized to GMT/UTC.

In Oracle Database, the `DATE` data type doesn't support fractional seconds or time zones. For fractional seconds you'd need to use any of the 3 `TIMESTAMP` data types. If you need to store the actual time zone, use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. If you don't need the actual time zone (most people don't) and want to make converting time zones really easy, then use `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`.

You haven't provided enough information to offer much of an answer, but here's a simple example that may sufficient:

```
select to_date('2016-07-13T07:38:15', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'),
  to_timestamp('2016-07-13T07:38:15.500Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF"Z"')
from dual;
```

Comment: Forgot to add my comment before, Thanks a ton for the help Dan